# Might this Livewire error be something about the BOM on windows files?

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

I have a windows computer where I am building a laravel project. I'm using livewire. Whenever I do a page load I get a DevTools warning informing me that it couldn't load the source map of:

```
     http://127.0.0.1:8000/livewire/livewire.j
```

The **.j instead of .js** is not a typo, it is actually the warning message.

Now, when I fill a field in any of the livewire components I get an error similar to this in my console:

```
    Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token ﻿ in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at livewire.js?id=940557fc56b15ccb9a2d:13:75044
```

Please note after **token** there is a **double space**, it might be hard to spot.

The class is still in the works (Of course it will be improved after I fix the problem), but basically I have this:

```
namespace App\Http\Livewire\People;

use App\Models\RequestURL;
use Illuminate\Contracts\View\View;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;
use Livewire\Component;

class Create extends Component
{
    // Variables that load data from the API
    public $countries;

    // Variables which send data to the API
    public ?string  $slug             = null;
    public ?string  $name             = '';
    public string   $mobile           = '';
    public ?int     $country_id       = null;
    public string   $person_type;
    public string   $person_type_plural;

    /**
     * Mounts the component
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function mount( string $person_type = 'employee', ?string $slug = null )
    {
        $this->person_type = $person_type;
        $this->person_type_plural = Str::plural( $person_type );

        if( $this->slug != null ){
            $this->slug = $slug;
            $response = new RequestURL( 'suppliers/'.Str::slug( $slug ), 'post' );

            $person = $response->getData()->person;
            $this->name = $person->name;
            $this->country_id = $person->document->country->id;
            $this->mobile = $person->mobile;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Actions when a field is updated
     *
     * @param $field
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function updated( $field )
    {
        dd( $field );
    }

    /**
     * Displays the component
     *
     * @return View
     */
    public function render() : View
    {
        return view( 'livewire.people.create' );
    }
}
```

I left the `updated` method like that, and it actually dumps the field name when I fill the name or

The code in my component's view is this:

```html
    <form>
        <div class="form-group">
            <span>Name: {{ $name }}</span>
            <input wire:model="name" type="text" class="form-control form-control-solid" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <span>Mobile: {{ $mobile }}</span>
            <input wire:model="mobile" type="text" class="form-control form-control-solid" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <span>Country: {{ $country_id }}</span>
            <select wire:model="country_id" class="form-select form-select-solid">
                <option value="">{{ __($person_type_plural . '.helpers.country') }}</option>
                @foreach($countries as $country)
                    <option value="{{ $country->id }}" @selected(old('country_id') == $country->id)>
                        {{ $country->name }}
                    </option>
                @endforeach
            </select>
        </div>
    </form>
```

I also tried removing all the other javascript in my layouts page and leaving only `<livewire:scripts />` to check if the error was coming from something loaded before livewire.js, but the error kept showing.

Answer (score 0):

If your on Windows I would suggest you using the WSL2 with your choice of Linux flavor. Then use Laravel Sail in conjection with Docker. This is what they also suggest in the Laravel Docs. https://laravel.com/docs/9.x#getting-started-on-windows